# Why does the billing information(country) change my prices?

Tags: checkout, price

My store is located in Germany and when my customer set the country in billing information for example to the USA the prices of all my products will go down a bit. What can be the reason for this and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's either because of tax or exchange rate.

Some payment service providers convert an order to, for example, USD instead of Euro when you send the client to pay. But honestly, I don't think that's it.

My best guess is tax. In the backend under `Sales > Tax` select `Manage Tax Zones and Rates`. Check if you have a tax rule for the US.

Under `Manage Tax Rules` in the same menu make sure that US rate is assigned to a rule.

Comment: Yes it was because I had no tax for the US